# Members in backoffice

Tags: umbraco, member

I am developing an application in Umbraco where I need to get my members from an external already existing database. I have succeeded in making a custom membership provider which I use to validate users.

What I would like to do now is to get the list of members in the external database to be visible in the members area in the backoffice. Is this possible and if so any ideas on how to accomplish it?

Comment: Heya! Would like to know if you ever managed to populate the Members section in the Back-Office from your external source? How did you accomplish it, what did the design look like? I'm currently trying to accomplish the same thing. Have implemented my own UmbracoMembershipProvider and can validate users from an SQL store, but Umbraco seems to want to have Members created in its internal database for things to work out properly - this I'm thinking about how to solve in an elegant way. Got any ideas? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

To achieve this you must build a custom member application for Umbraco.

== Edit on request ==

The member gui is explicitly built to handle Umbraco Member Objects, these object can be extended with properties of the same data types as all objects in Umbraco. This gui won't simply work with a regular asp.net membership provider since they are not compatible.

To best match this you should extend the *umbraco.providers.members*.**UmbracoMembershipProvider** class instead of the ordinary asp.net membership provider.

Now, you can make calls from the UmbracoMembershipProvider to any asp.net membership provider but this is a discussion of architecture and philosophy :)

Comment: Can you explain in your answer why you think it is not possible? I will happily remove my down vote if you can support and expand on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar requirement in a previous project. We created a scheduled task that used a secure web service to collect the users and then programmatically added them into the Umbraco backoffice. The scheduled task had to check for existing users in order to avoid duplicate entries.

Also, the passwords of the users would need to be available in plain text in order for them to be added into Umbraco. If they aren't, then you will need to create a new password for each user which may be impractical.

See here for [more information on the membership api](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers).

Comment: When you say that you added them into the Umbraco backoffice, do you mean that you save them in Umbracos own database?

Comment: Yes, Umbraco's API will allow you to programmatically save new members and these will be added into Umbraco's database.

Comment: Ok, thank your answer. It's doable but it will mean that I have the members in two separate databases at the same time, doesn't seem optimal but maybe the best way to go.